# Invalid Data in Excel File. Index was outside the bounds of the array.C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, postgresql

Cant find answer in any of the suggestions.I am trying to upload an excel file to the postgre Db.

**Here is the C# code :**

```
 public static List<Common.Transactions.TransactionDetail> GetTransactionDetails(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            return null;
        }
        var transactionDetails = new List<Common.Transactions.TransactionDetail>();
        foreach (var sheet in Workbook.Worksheets(path))
        {
            int officeId = 0;
            foreach (var row in sheet.Rows.Skip(1))
            {
                var td = new Common.Transactions.TransactionDetail
                {
                    GlAccountId = Core.GlAccounts.GetGlAcccountId(row.Cells[1]?.Text),
                    AccountNumberId = Deposit.AccountHolders.GetAccountNumberId(row.Cells[2]?.Text),
                    ShareAccountId = Core.ShareAccounts.GetShareAccountId(row.Cells[3]?.Text),
                    LoanId = Loan.LoanAccounts.GetLoanId(row.Cells[4]?.Text),
                    Debit = row.Cells[5]?.Text.ToDecimal(),
                    Credit = row.Cells[6]?.Text.ToDecimal(),
                    StatementReference = row.Cells[7]?.Text
                };


                if (row.Cells[7] != null)
                {
                    td.OfficeId = Office.Offices.GetOfficeIdByCode(row.Cells[7]?.Text);
                    officeId = Office.Offices.GetOfficeIdByCode(row.Cells[7]?.Text);
                }



                if (td.AccountNumberId == 0)
                {
                    td.AccountNumberId = null;
                }
                if (td.LoanId == 0)
                {
                    td.LoanId = null;
                }
                if (td.ShareAccountId == 0)
                {
                    td.ShareAccountId = null;
                }

                if (row.Cells[0] != null)
                {
                    td.AccountName = row.Cells[0].Text;
                }
                if (row.Cells[1] != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(td.AccountName))
                {
                    td.AccountName = row.Cells[1].Text;
                }
                if (row.Cells[2] != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(td.AccountName))
                {
                    td.AccountName = row.Cells[2].Text;
                }
                if (row.Cells[3] != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(td.AccountName))
                {
                    td.AccountName = row.Cells[3].Text;
                }

                #region OfficeId
                if (td.AccountNumberId != null)
                {
                    officeId = Deposit.AccountHolders.GetAccountOfficeId(td.AccountNumberId.ToLong());
                }
                if (td.LoanId != null)
                {
                    officeId = Loan.LoanGrant.GetAccountOfficeId(td.LoanId.ToLong());
                }
                if (td.ShareAccountId != null)
                {
                    officeId = Core.ShareAccounts.GetAccountOfficeId(td.ShareAccountId.ToLong());
                }

                #endregion

                td.OfficeId = officeId != 0 ? officeId : SessionHelper.GetOfficeId();
                td.OfficeCode = Office.Offices.GetOfficeCode(officeId);

                transactionDetails.Add(td);
            }
        }
        foreach (var detail in transactionDetails)
        {
            if (detail.Debit.ToDecimal() > 0 && detail.Credit > 0)
            {
                throw new TransactionDetailException(
                    $@"Invalid transaction. Either debit or credit should be null for '{detail.AccountName}'.");
            }
            if (detail.AccountNumberId > 0)
            {
                if (detail.Debit.ToDecimal() > 0)
                {
                    if (detail.Debit > Deposit.AccountHolders.GetDepositAccountBalance(detail.AccountNumberId.ToLong()))
                    {
                        throw new TransactionDetailException(
                            $@"Insufficient balance in account '{detail.AccountName}'.");
                    }
                }
                detail.GlAccountId = Deposit.AccountHolders.GetGlAccountId(detail.AccountNumberId);
            }

            if (detail.ShareAccountId > 0)
            {
                if (detail.Debit.ToDecimal() > 0)
                {
                    if (detail.Debit > Core.ShareAccounts.GetShareBalance(detail.ShareAccountId.ToLong()))
                    {
                        throw new TransactionDetailException(
                            $@"Insufficient balance in account '{detail.AccountName}'.");
                    }
                }
                detail.GlAccountId = Core.ShareAccounts.GetGlAccountId(detail.ShareAccountId.ToLong());
            }

            if (detail.LoanId > 0)
            {
                if (detail.Credit.ToDecimal() > 0)
                {
                    if (detail.Credit > Loan.LoanAccounts.GetLoanCollectionBalance(detail.LoanId.ToLong(), Core.DateConversion.GetCurrentServerDate()))
                    {
                        throw new TransactionDetailException(
                            $@"Insufficient balance in account '{detail.AccountName}'.");
                    }
                }
                detail.GlAccountId = Loan.LoanGrant.GetLoanTransactionGLAccountId(detail.LoanId.ToLong());
            }

            detail.AuditUserId = Common.Helpers.SessionHelper.GetUserId();
            detail.AccountNumberId = detail.AccountNumberId <= 0 ? null : detail.AccountNumberId;
            detail.LoanId = detail.LoanId <= 0 ? null : detail.LoanId;
            detail.ShareAccountId = detail.ShareAccountId <= 0 ? null : detail.ShareAccountId;
            detail.EnableDeleteButton = true;

            if (detail.GlAccountId == 0)
            {
                throw new TransactionDetailException($@"{detail.AccountName} is not a valid account.");
            }
        }
        return transactionDetails;
    }
}
```

I get error Index was outside the bounds of array.Invalid excel data.

**My excel data**

```
Gl Account  Deposit A/C Share A/C   Loan A/C    Debit   Credit  Statement Reference
```

Loss Recovery Fund              0   1000    uploaded from excel
Risk Coverage Fund              0   1106    uploaded from excel

Comment: Place a breakpoint in your code and step through it.Identify the line of code which is causing the "Index Out Of Bounds" exception and put in corrective code to prevent the error or stop accessing the elemnt with an invalid index

Comment: I would expect this to be out of bounds: `row.Cells[0]`. Excel starts counting its ranges with 1, not 0.

Comment: @LocEngineer So what must be wrong sir?

Comment: @OLDMONK start with index 1 sir

Comment: @LocEngineer do you mean instead of starting from row.Cells[0]?.Text i should with row.Cells[1]?.Text?? I am still learning sir..pardon me if too naive.

Comment: Yes exactly. Start with `row.Cells[1]`, and no: that is not naive of you but a little _peculiar_ by Microsoft. :-)

Comment: @LocEngineer Same error sir..i have edited the question.Can you please check it.

Comment: 1.) You still have `if (row.Cells[0] != null)`
2.) Please single-step through your code using F8. We need to know where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: I am getting the glaccount id null.

Comment: The error might be in your `GetGlAcccountId(int id)` method. Let's see that.

Comment: Starting at index 0-  the expection throws at this--  if (row.Cells[7] != null)
                    {
                        td.OfficeId = Office.Offices.GetOfficeIdByCode(row.Cells[7]?.Text);
                        officeId = Office.Offices.GetOfficeIdByCode(row.Cells[7]?.Text);
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it..The problem was with my excel data.

I was looking for row[7] which didnt exist.Had to add one column to the 
excel file and it worked.

The exception was here in the code :

```
 if (row.Cells[7] != null)
            {
                td.OfficeId = Office.Offices.GetOfficeIdByCode(row.Cells[7]?.Text);
                officeId = Office.Offices.GetOfficeIdByCode(row.Cells[7]?.Text);
            }
```

Thanks @LocEngineer Sir for your time.